# MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: Unable to connect to server. A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup

Tags: mongodb, wcf

My service is able to connect to the MongoDB installed in a server. Am able to get the collection of the MongoDB. But when I try to insert a record to that collection it showing the below error.

MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: Unable to connect to server xxxxxxxxx. A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance..
Santyy